# Set pandas datetime index one day forward

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Is it possible to set one day forward a datetime index in pandas?

I've got this index

```
mydata.data.index
Out[7]: <class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-01-27 22:00:00, ..., 2014-12-16 22:00:00]
Length: 500, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

and its wrong. The correct date that the data begin is the day after. That is 2014-12-17 and they end at 2013-01-28

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: "28.0.2014"; when did/does that happen?

Comment: For consistenty and clarify, use the same format (`yyyy-mm-dd`) in your text as in your code.

Comment: Yes that was a typo excuse me. I am just used to the European format ill correct it.

Comment: Your end is before your begin date; you probably mean the other way 'round.

Comment: I don't know Pandas well, but I would try by adding `datetime.timedelta(1)` to `mydata.data.index` and see what happens.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some different options:

Use the [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.shift.html) method:

```
In [10]: dti = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=2)

In [11]: dti
Out[11]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-01, 2012-01-02]
Length: 2, Freq: D, Timezone: None

In [13]: dti.shift(1, freq='D')
Out[13]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-02, 2012-01-03]
Length: 2, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

But maybe more easy (as @Evert notices), you can simply add a timedelta of one day:

```
In [14]: dti + pd.Timedelta('1 day')
Out[14]:
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-02, 2012-01-03]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

For older pandas versions, you can also just use `datetime.timedelta(days=1)` (`pd.Timedelta` is only avaible starting from 0.15).